# Change accent colour on Touch Bar?

Tags: macos, color, touch-bar

If I go to `System Preferences>General>Accent colour` and change it, the accent colour changes across the whole system, right?

Wrong. The Touch Bar still uses blue, no matter what. See this:
[image: Xcode dialog box using orange as accent colour; "Done" is in orange for example]

but on the Touch Bar:
[image: Touch Bar with blue "Done" button and grey "Cancel" button]

How do I fix this and make the Touch Bar use *orange* as the accent colour?
(this isn't just in Xcode, it's in every app).